# Getting a binary file from an angular resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use an angular resource to get a binary file. I am able to do this with an http.get.

```
return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/users/my_user/avatar", {responseType:'arraybuffer'});
```

This returns a string of the file. That is what I want.

When trying to use the resource:

```
var resource4 = $resource('/users/:userId/avatar',{},{'get':{method:'GET',cache:false,responseType:'arraybuffer'},'getCached':{method:'GET',cache:true,responseType:'arraybuffer'}, 'postList':{method:'POST', isArray:true}});
```

I return an object with a get method here:

```
getAvatar: function(userId, successCallback, errorCallback) {

                var requestData = { userId: convertValueForRest(userId)};
                return resource4.get(requestData, successCallback, errorCallback);

            }
```

Then I inject it into a service and pass it through:

```
function getAvatar(user){
    return UserDetailsInterface.getAvatar(user);
}
```

I grab the data from $promise here:

```
UserPreferences.getAvatar(userName).$promise
                    .then(function success(image){
```

What is returned is the file's characters split out into a huge array. I am really not sure why.

Comment: Try setting `isArray: false` in the get config

Comment: That does not seem to work. I thought that isArray defaulted to false if omitted.

Answer (score 10):

I figured out the problem. I needed to add transformResponse to handle the arraybuffer being returned in the resource.

```
transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) { return { data : data }}
```

This answer was what I needed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24290186/5838629